# Best way to move XML data from a SQL Server 2016 DB to Cosmos DB

Tags: sql-server, azure-cosmosdb, sql-server-2016

Have a SQL Server 2016 table which contains ~10 GB of data. I have to migrate the XML data stored within that table in a XML column to Cosmos DB.

It's a one time job and post migration such data would be directly written into Cosmos DB (from an API written on C#).

What is the best way to migrate this? I am aware there is a Azure Cosmos DB Migration tool but not aware how to migrate the XML column using that. Also is there any other better solutions for this?

Comment: You know there is a tool, but have not tried it?

Comment: Thanks for assuming that I haven't tried!! Strange to see even without understanding the question you go about down-voting the question. I did try but not succeeded as i don't know how to migrate it. Also folks were saying cosmos db isn't good for xml you need to change it to json before doing it. That's why i had asked what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Xml data into JSON within SQL Server 2016. It shouldn't be a very hard task..  batch it out.

pseudo-Code:

```
    DECLARE @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <header>
       <rdms id="1">
          <sqlserver>MSSQL1</sqlserver>
       </rdms>
       <rdms id="1">
          <sqlserver>MSSQL2</sqlserver>
       </rdms>
       <rdms id="2">
          <oracle11g>cc11</oracle11g>
       </rdms>
     </header>''';

SELECT x.value('@id', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS rdms
    ,x.value('sqlserver[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS [Server]
    ,x.value('oracle11g[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS [Oracle]
FROM @xml.nodes('/header/rdms') AS a(x)
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Then use the Cosmosdb Migration tool to load the JSON data into CosmosDB...

Read on the below..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type